# Group and split variable in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: string, oracle, variables, plsql, split

I want to split this variable into may so that limit in IN clause is handled in PLSQL.

```
SELECT codeid from code table where codename in (code_string);
```

code_string has values like 'abc1',abc2','abc3'.....abc175000

So I want `code_string` should be split into group of 1000 codes and provide to the query so limit for IN clause is handles.

Query looks like something like this

```
SELECT codeid from code table where codename in ('abc1',abc2','abc3'.....abc1000);
```

PLease provide the solution.

Comment: If number of codes can be > 1000, you may want to put these values in a temporary table and join to your main table.  Will need to know more about how you plan to use this, where the code values are coming from, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CONNECT BY` and `regexp_substr` to split your string, example:

```
WITH
  test_data AS (
    SELECT 'abc' AS val FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 'abc1' FROM dual
    UNION SELECT 'abc2' FROM dual
  )
SELECT *
  FROM test_data
WHERE
  val IN (
    SELECT regexp_substr('abc1,abc2,abc3', '[^,]+', 1, level) FROM dual
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr('abc1,abc2,abc3', '[^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
);
```

The `CONNECT BY` and `regexp_substr` will tokenize input string and you'll be able to use the result set in the `IN` clause.

Output:

```
VAL
----
abc1 
abc2
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/20207)

Comment: code_string Varchar2(2000):='abc1','abc2','abc3'.....'abc175000';                 Code_string is declared as above..how will you use this code_string in CONNECT BY and regexp_substr??

Comment: @Shabz Just put the `code_string` in the `SELECT` and `CONNECT BY`, instead of `regexp_substr('abc1,abc2,abc3'` use `regexp_substr(code_string`